# Using Wordpress gallery plugin through php use shortcode with my custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, themes

I'm using wordpress as a backend to my website, and trying to use foogallery as a gallery for my client to upload their own images to.

My problem is that I've made the gallery in wordpress, connected it to my index.php through , but for some reason my gallery simply isn't working. Instead I just get a page that looks like this

[image: screenshot of what gallery looks like]

If I click the images they bring me to their own page with just the image on it, instead of getting the lightbox plugin associated with it.

Here is the code on my index.php

```
<?php /* Template Name: CustomPageT1 */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="content">
            <?php echo do_shortcode( '[foogallery id="33"]' ); ?>   
        </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```